# How to return a typed list of inherited objects?

Tags: angular

have a problem that is driving me crazy.

I have a list of objects in the c# backend, in the way of

```
public class A {
  public string PropertyA {
    get;
    set;
  }
}

public class B :A {
  public string PropertyB {
    get;
    set; 
  }
}

public class C: A{
  public string PropertyC {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

And return from the backend a list of {B,C}

Now, in angular have the same class structure, and exact properties, inheritance ,etc

I wat to make an http get to that backend , take that list and translate to a list of angular {B,C} types, not sure if possible, but i cant find the way. I get a list of items with different properties, but no type on each one

Any thoughts?

Comment: try `this.http.get<(B|C)[]>(url)`

Comment: Thanks A.Winnen, but it ends in the same result as before. I have the angular list of objects, with correct properties,etc . But none of the elements has the correct B or C types, are just "objects"

Comment: how shall typescript know what exact class the object is? You need to tell the compiler the type. If you know that some object is of type B, you can tell the compiler to treat the object as type B by using `(object as B)`: It is still instanceof Object though.
If you really want the object to of type B, you'll need to create the object using B's constructor. Then you can also check which type it is using instanceof

Comment: Yes, tried to cast with as but it still a "object" . Creating with B constructor is ok but how to map then the whole object properties into created? . You are right , looks no way typescript know the type, but as get get<x]> maps the object into x i (wrongly) supposed the inherited objects works the same way.

Thaks

Comment: `Object.assign(new B(), objectFromApi)`

Comment: Looks it works for me! , following your suggestion did this (not sure if something is not needed, but it works)

this.http.get("").pipe(map(data=>map(item:any)=>{
 var t = Object.assign(new B(), item);
return t;
}

Many thanks!

Comment: you should be using Interceptor for this it was built for what you are trying to do. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have one list in your angular app based on a Web-API call, It's better to make a single list in your back-end and just assign it to your angular list. in the angular code create a model that have all of the B and C properties. something like this:

```
export class BCClass {
  B_property_1: any;
  B_property_2: any;
  B_property_3: any;
  C_property_1: any;
  C_property_2: any;
  C_property_3: any;
}
```

then inside your service define a list of that type:

```
public dataList: BCClass = new BCClass ();
```

But if you want to get two different list from your back-end API and combine them in your component or service in angular app, the best way is using typescript **spread** operator. here is an example:

```
var arr1 = [0, 1, 2];
var arr2 = [3, 4, 5];
arr1 = [...arr2, ...arr1];
```

for more information about that see the following links:

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/spread-operator.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Hope these explanations can help you.

Comment: Thanks ng-hobby, will take a look to links. Cant create a combined class because all that models in my angular app are autogenerated from c# classes.

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways you can do this but you should be using Angular `HttpInterceptor` for this, it was build to solve this exact issue - https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Here is an example of handling a response and modifying the body, will not be exactly what you need you will have to change the parsing but it will lead you down the path you need:

```
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class HttpResponseBodyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  public intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
      tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          event = event.clone({ body: this.modifyBody(event) });
        }
        return event;
      }),
    );
  }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
  private modifyBody(event: HttpResponse<any>): void {
    if (event.url === 'YOUR_URL_API_ENDPOINT') {
      // fine your body property and cast it here
      // just a example below
      // this then means your class response types can be strongly
      // typed
      event.body['A'] = new YourClassName(event.body['A']);
    }
  }
}
```

don't forget to register it in your `app.module.ts` providers

```
   {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: HttpResponseBodyInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
```